# Angular 2 - can I use *ngIf in the <link rel='stylesheet' tag in in the <head> section?

Tags: html, css, angular

Angular 2 - can I use *ngIf in the link/stylesheet tag in in the head section?

I want something like this:

```
link rel='stylesheet' href="../assets/css/styles1.css" *ngIf="myvar === 'example'"
```

Thanks

Comment: I want to conditionalize the entire stylesheet for the app - not just individual elements.  Isn't ngStyle used for specific divs, spans, ... ?

Comment: No you can't do this at runtime. While the `<head>` section of your document is being processed, angular is booting up and not available at this time. You can append stylesheets to the head by using JS though.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4202#issuecomment-339420111
By @TRAHOMOTO

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme/css/vendor-rtl.min.css" *ngIf="(locale$ | async)?.isRtl else ltrVendor">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme/css/common-rtl.min.css" *ngIf="(locale$ | async)?.isRtl else ltrCommon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme/css/application-rtl.min.css" *ngIf="(locale$ | async)?.isRtl else ltrApplication">

    <ng-template #ltrVendor>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme/css/vendor.min.css">
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #ltrCommon>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme/css/common.min.css">
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #ltrApplication>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme/css/application.min.css">
    </ng-template>
```

Comment: Not in the head of the html document.

Comment: You can do that in your app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

HTML:

`<head>
   <link id="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
</head>`

TS:

`import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

`constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }`

`ngOnInit() {
      this.document.getElementById('stylesheet').setAttribute('href', 'style2.css');
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Directives and Angular bindings can only be used in the template of an Angular component.

You can't make the `<head>`element an Angular application, because making an element an Angular application purges the elements original content.
Angular components can only be added inside an Angular applications root element.

The only option is to use imperative code (like shown in izulito's answer).